# Writing command synopsis in standard man format

Tags: shell-script, documentation, parameter

I am writing a script and in the `usage()` function I want to specify the usage.
My script uses either option1 or option2 or both. One of them is mandatory.

Is there a standard way to write it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you talk about simplest usage information optional parameters are listed in `[]`.

For example usage section from `man`:

```
usage: man [-adfhktwW] [section] [-M path] [-P pager] [-S list]
    [-m system] [-p string] name ...
```

So if your script can accept `option1` and `option2` but they aren't mandatory you can display it like this:

```
script [option1] [option2]
```

Comment: Actually one of them is mandatory.

Comment: So it should be without `[]`